# svn cat or svnlook

Tags: svn

How do you decide when to use svn cat or svnlook? To my understanding svn cat is used on working copies and svnlook is used on repositories.

If I wanted to look at all the files in a working copy through a repository with svn look, how would I do this?

I know that there is a subcommand dirs-changed, but that only displays the changed directories. I want to be able to acquire both a list of files in the path and a list of directories in that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point between them is: `svnlook` does **not** work with URLs. Hence you can use it only on repositories. And if you access the repository via a protocol like `svn://` or `http://` then `svnlook` will not work on the client side - it will work only on the server side when called via hook-scripts for example.

So when you say: "[...] in a working copy through a repository with svn look [...]" then this is just impossible.  Either you are on the server side - then you have no access to the working copy. Or you are on the client side - then you have no (useful) access to `svnlook`.

Comment: `svnlook` is a tool for *administrators* who have full access to a repository on a filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

`svnlook` can only operate on local filesystem paths for the repository, not URLs. It's meant to be used on your repository server within hook scripts to inspect a specific revision or transaction.

`svn cat` is a client-side tool that can be pointed at repository URLs or a working copy path. It simply dumps the content of the file or URL to `STDOUT`.

If you're dealing with a working copy, you need to be using `svn`, not `svnlook`.